# Doing aggregation on object in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to do an aggregation on one of the object type but I couldn't make it work. I created a mapping from `dynamic_templates` because my object is dictionary and the key is list of constants. Here is my object, mapping and aggregate query.. even I can't access indexed field by must->exists query.

Document

```
{
  "property":{
    "innerProperty":{
       "constantKey":{
          "someArrays":[
             {
                "id":"12345"
             }
          ]
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Mapping

```
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "property_map": {
        "path_match": "property.innerProperty.*",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "object",
          "dynamic": false
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Mapping result after adding a document

```
  "property": {
    "properties": {
      "innerProperty": {
        "properties": {
          "constantKey": {
            "type": "object",
            "dynamic": "false"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Aggregation

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "property.innerProperty.constantKey"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "property-agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "property.innerProperty.constantKey"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Both of aren't working. I would like to do an aggregation by constantKey so that I would get the correct document count to facets make it work.

Comment: term aggregation is group by and you can group by a single value. So grouping on object is not possible. What you want to achieve? Do you need total count of objects under constantKey?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal yes I would like to count how many constantKey I have.